# How do I get documents more recent than a particular document in Mongoid?

Tags: ruby, mongoid

I am trying to do something like this in mongoid:

```
User.any_in(:uid => friends).and(:id.gt =>  "4d391ab448fa7d389b000000").entries
```

But looks like Mongoid ID cannot be compared this way. How do I achieve the above without resorting to using Mongoid::Timestamps ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why would you not want to use timestamps?

Using ids in this way will not give you the behavior you want.

The id of the document will depend not only on the order of insertion but also on what machine the id was generated on.

Timestamps are definitely your best bet here.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use server side javascript to process the values but that would be less efficient and less secure if you care for these properties.